# How to cast any to DocumentSnapshot in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function:

```
async function getUser() {
  const ref = doc(db, "users/john/");
  const document = await getDoc(ref);
  if(document.exists()) {
    //Print details
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call `exists()` but it doesn't work as the document is seen as `any` and not `DocumentSnapshot`. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you writing typescript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, simple plain JavaScript code.

Comment: JavaScript does not know an `any` type or an `DocumentSnapshot` type, therefor you cannot cast one into the other. Instead, `console.log` the return value of `await getDoc(ref)` to see what it is - might be it is _not_ what you think it is. Besides, using a constant named `document` isn't a very clever idea in a browser context - better use a different name because at least in Chrome assignment to `const document` results in an SyntaxError.

Comment: @David This is what my IntelliJ says, it's `any`. If I print, is prints the content of the document if I call data(). However, IntelliJ  complains with `Unresolved function or method data() `. So should I use `let` instead of `const`?

Comment: @JoanP. doesn't really matter what the IDE says. Consider using JSDoc if you want type hints in regular JS? Also, rename `document` to something else.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you. What's the point of renaming the `document` to something else?

Comment: @JoanP. `document` is a [pre-existing global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). Consider renaming the local variable? Unless this is running in node, and then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoanP. Well, you should understand the difference between your IDE and the browser ;-) That your IDE says the inferred type is "any" is a result of you using _JavaScript_, so the Typescript-based type inference in IntelliJ cannot infer the type. This has nothing to do with the fact that it does not work in the browser. And the reason why you should not use `document` is that `document` is an already defined constant in the browser. It doesn't matter if you use `let` or `const`, the problem ist the _name_ `document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks have explained in the comments, your IDE is likely getting confused by the `document` variable name. When you run JavaScript in a browser context, `document` is a global variable referring to the currently loaded document, which indeed does not have any `exists` or `data` methods or properties.

The easiest way to prevent this confusion is to use a different name for the variable. I typically call is snapshot:

```
async function getUser() {
  const ref = doc(db, "users/john/");
  const snapshot = await getDoc(ref);
  if(snapshot.exists()) {
    //Print details
  }
}
```